# How to play a video every hour in ubuntu

Tags: video, ubuntu-14.04, playback, schedule

I have a video of 5min duration in my home folder in ubuntu. The video has to be played every hour in the foreground. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I think the simplest solution.
Type in terminal: crontab -e and choice editor (if this is the first launch).
And insert it:

```
0 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && vlc /home/user/video_name.mp4
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

vlc - my favorite videoplayer)) You may use other)) Good luck!
Read more about cron - [click](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: why do i need to add the shell & the path?

Comment: @user27665, SHELL - tells the system which shell to use, PATH - paths that are searched for the calling program.

Comment: with the command as yours, i used totem instead of vlc. the totem viewer opens and exits immedietly without playing any video

Comment: @user27665, Hmm, strange, I do not know why so totem behaves.